# $74x \equiv 1 \bmod 53$

Tags: congruences

I've figured out that $x=-5$ for this to work but I don't know how to state the general solution? (all cases)

Anyone know? D:

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If you have two solutions, $x_1$ and $x_2$, then
$$
74x_1\equiv74x_2\pmod{53}
$$
Since $\gcd(53,74)=1$, what does
$$
53\mid74(x_1-x_2)
$$
imply?

Comment: One doesn't need Euclid's Lemma (or Bezout's identity) to deduce *uniqueness of inverses*. Rather, this is true in any commutative monoid, since it can be proved using only associativity and commutativity of multiplication - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, write the congruence as
$$74x = 1 + 53y$$

where $y$ is any integer.  Then,
$$74x - 53y = 1$$

As you said before, $x = -5$ (and so $y = -7$, which works for congruence).  Then, there are more solutions $x = -5 + 53k$ where $k$ is any integer.

Comment: When answering homework questions it is most useful to [avoid complete answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,a',a\,$ are solutions of $\,74x\equiv 1$ then $\,a'$ times $\,1\equiv 74a\,\Rightarrow\,  a'\equiv\, \ldots\ $ Conversely $(\Leftarrow)$ multiplying
$\, a'\equiv\, \ldots\,$ by  $\,74\,$ shows $\,74a'\equiv 74(\dots)\,$ so if one of them is $\equiv 1\,$ then they both are.

Above we invoked a few times the fundamental  Congruence Product Rule - see below. The converse works more generally:  $\,a'\equiv a,\,\ f(a)\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, f(a')\equiv 0,\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with *integer* coefficients, see the Polynomial Congruence Rule below.

---

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#0a0}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c00}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence Power Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ A^n\equiv a^n\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Polynomial Congruence Rule** $\ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is polynomial with *integer* coefficients then  $\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ f(A)\equiv f(a)\,\pmod m.$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\, n = $ degree $f.\,$ Clear if $\, n = 0.\,$ Else $\,f(x) = f(0) + x\,g(x)\,$ for $\,g(x)\,$ a polynomial with integer coefficients of degree $< n.\,$  By induction $\,g(A)\equiv g(a)\,$ so $\, A g(A)\equiv a g(A)\,$ by the Product Rule. Hence $\,f(A) = f(0)+Ag(A)\equiv f(0)+ag(a) = f(a)\,$ by the Sum Rule.

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it reduces to the Power Rule, so follows by inductively applying $\,\rm b\,$ times the Product Rule).

Comment: Wait, I'm actually a bit confused by this.  How does this answer the question posed by OP?

Comment: @Alexander How doesn't it?

Comment: If my understanding is correct he is asking how to find (to compute) the other x's for which this works, i.e. how to get from his partial answer to a full one. I'm not sure which part of your post addresses that (but admittedly I am a bit confused by your ellipsis notation- I'm not saying this is a bad answer, just that I don't understand and would like to).

Comment: @Alex I interpreted the question as follows. Given the "congruences" tag, the OP is working with congruences (vs. quotient rings, and may not have knowledge of rings). The OP has a *particular* solution $\,a\in\Bbb Z\,$ of the congruence $\,74x\equiv 1\pmod{53}$ and seeks the *general* solution, i.e. all integers which satisfy this congruence. The hint sketches a proof that the integer solutions are precisely the congruence class of any particular solution, i.e. solutions are unique mod $\,m.\,$ Did you interpret the question differently?

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle 74\equiv21, 74x\equiv1\pmod{53}\iff 21x\equiv1\iff x\equiv21^{-1}\equiv3^{-1}\cdot7^{-1}$

Now as $18\cdot3=54\equiv1\pmod{53}\iff3^{-1}\equiv18$

and $53\cdot2-7\cdot15=1\implies 7(-15)\equiv1\pmod{53}\iff7^{-1}\equiv-15$

$\displaystyle\implies x\equiv18(-15)\pmod{53}\equiv-5\equiv48$

So, we can write $x=-5+53a=48+53(a-1)=48+53b$ where $a,b$ are any integers